How to get the Pod dependency which is there on github releases as an asset
I have an XCFramework generated which is more than 100MB. So I have compressed it into zip and uploaded it as a release asset. Similar to like this Asset BrazeKit.zip
The assets zip contains the framework which i intent to add as a dependency in XCode iOS project.
Now how can i configure podspec file so that i add the dependency using Cocoapods, Pod init and defining the dependency using pod so that it would be added when i do Pod install.
I tried adding the zip link as source in podspec but it is not downloading the assets zip file.
s.source = { :http => 'https://github.com/braze-inc/braze-swift-sdk/releases/download/9.3.0/BrazeKit.zip' }
Note: The above zip link is not my github repo, its just a reference.
